# Bounded Diameter Spanning Tree problem for directed graphs

Tags: algorithms, graphs

The following undirected version of Bounded Diameter Spanning Tree problem is solvable in Polynomial Time.

**Undirected Version:** Given an undirected Graph $G = (V, E)$ with each edge weight either 1 or 2; 2 positive integers $B$, and $D<=3$.

Problem Statement: Is there a spanning tree $T$ of $G$ such that the sum of weights of the edges in T does not exceed $B$ and such that $T$ contains no simple path with more than $D$ edges?

**Directed Version:** Now lets consider a same problem for a Directed Graph. With much more simpler constraints: Let each edge have the same weight 1, let $B=\infty$ (thus irrelevant), and let $D<2$.

Problem Statement: Is there a "spanning forest" $T$ of $G$ such that the sum of weights of the edges in T does not exceed $B$ and such that $T$ contains no simple path with more than $D$ edges?

I am struggling with how to approach the problem for the Directed version (though it has much less constraints than the undirected version). Can anyone please provide some inputs on the approach?

Comment: How do you solve the undirected version? Does the algorithm carry over? If not, why not?

Comment: Much Thanks. To be honest, the information I have is that from Garey and Jhonson [ND4] where they mentioned the following "Can be easily solved in Polynomial Time if D<=3 or if all edges are weighted equal". But, I believe (without much direction to go about it), that the simpler version with less constraints would follow from it. The reduction is using Exact cover by 2-sets. But, frankly I haven't been able to come up with a similar correspondence or an idea for directed version .

Comment: 1. Do I understand that Garey & Johnson gave you a citation (namely, [ND4]) for where you can read more?  If so, have you read the paper they cited?  If not, a good next step would be to read that paper, understand their polynomial-time algorithm, then update the question with a summary of that information.  2. What have you tried?  Have you tried to find an algorithm for the undirected version for $D=2$?  Have you tried thinking about an algorithm for the directed version for $D=2$?  What ideas have you considered so far?  What's your definition of "spanning tree" for the latter?

Comment: Thanks. 1.) I don't have the access to the paper and I am trying to get it. 2.) The definition of a Directed Spanning Tree is as follows: Assuming we ignore the direction of the edges the resultant sub-Graph is a spanning tree for the undirected graph. 3.) Regarding D<=2. It implies that there are no 2 pair of Nodes (a, b) in the directed version of Spanning tree such that there exists a path [a-> x -> y -> b] as if this were the case it violates D <=2 as here D=3.

Comment: 4.) Moreover on second thought even if the constraint was: (a) D<2 (b) the Spanning Tree was relaxed to Spanning Forest. Even then the Problem for the directed Graph under new constraints I am struggling with. Thus, I am updating the Question. [P.S. For the undirected one, I assume we can simply do a BFS Tree or something similar].

Comment: can anyone please provide some pointers? 1) The approach I have tried is using a BFS tree but that would not work in the case of directed Graphs. 2) The second approach would be using the exact cover but that seems also suitable for undirected Graphs as far as I think.